# Boldly taken postulates

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Einstein's Special theory of relativity was a landmark in physics, which totally changed our viewpoint of observing physical phenomena. While proposing his new theory, Einstein assumed two simple but bold postulates. When we enter into the amazing palace of Special theory of relativity, these two postulates act as the front gate of the theory. Here, one of the postulates is- 
Speed of light in vaccum has the same value c in all inertial frames.

But how Einstein could accept the postulate without directly proving it?

Comment: It didn't take any "boldness" in that sense. Einstein knew that he wanted to reproduce the Lorentz transformations (which were known at the time) to have Maxwell's equations invariant under the theory. The only "bold" step, if you like, was to chose electrodynamics over classical mechanics as the more fundamental theory and then to modify mechanics to make the resulting theory compatible with electrodynamics. For teaching purposes it is easier to go the other way round and derive the Lorentz transformations from a postulate, but the science history is the other way round.

Comment: Suppose light is going away from me at its own speed and I am in a frame of reference which is going opposite at the same speed. Will the speed of light remain same from my point of view?

Comment: We aren't "supposing" anything. All of this has been measured with extremely high accuracy.

Comment: In my opinion, if something at some point leads you to a single postulate(or more than one), or has begun from one(or more), then incompleteness is still in the picture. Therefore, this "acceptance", is quite puzzling indeed !

Comment: All the measurements were taken after the origination of the theory, not before it's birth. Even gravitational waves are also the consequences of his theory, but it's proved after hundred years. Perhaps, no body would have searched it, if it was not predicted by Einstein.

Comment: That Maxwell's equations were correct was backed up by a century of optical experiments. In 1905 there was not the slightest shred of concern about their validity. On the other hand, Einstein would have known that there were no relevant observations on mechanical systems with velocities exceeding approx. 47km/s (the orbital velocity of Mercury). Therefor everything Newtonian mechanics had to say about velocities close to the speed of light was conjecture.

Comment: @PriyankushDeka "I am in a frame of reference which is going opposite at the same speed." You're going at what speed relative to what? If you're going at speed $c$ away from the light, there are an infinity of possible reference frames that you might be referring to.

Comment: A *postulate* is *by definition* something which you take to be true without proving it. That is literally the meaning of the word - something taken to be true without proof for the discussion that follows. Are you actually trying to ask what the *motivation* for taking this as a postulate is (because asking for *proof* of a postulate is by its very nature non-sensical)?

Comment: Exactly. That'what I was asking. I was curious to know, how others take these postulates before entering deep into the field. Though it's a postulate, it should not be wrong. So Einstein must have thought deeply before assuming it. If it'd have been so simple and obvious, others could propose it as well.

Comment: I'm taking the earth as the frame of reference. From the earth's point of view, a souce of light and I are going with speed c and exactly in the opposite direction. Then what will be the speed of the light source from my point of view. (In classical mechanics, the speed would have been twice the speed of light!!) @CR Drost

Comment: @PriyankushDeka You can't travel at the speed of light in the Earth's frame of reference -- you are a massive being who experiences time and whose experience of the universe is not one-dimensional but four-dimensional. Similarly a "source of light" (a lamp?) is unlikely to do the same. Is it sufficient to help your understanding for me to answer the question when you are both going at 9/10ths the speed of light, so that in classical mechanics the speed would be 1.8 times the speed of light?

Comment: @CR Drost Yes, please elaborate what will happen in that case (speed is 9/10 times the speed of light)?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so, we've reduced the question a bit in the comments of the post: the question is now something like, "how did Einstein accept something which directly implies a strange cosmic speed limit when it so firmly contradicts our everyday experiences?" or so.

## Some notes on the history of the development of these things

As many have noted, part of this question is essentially historical. To that extent, a brief history of the ideas is in order. Several thinkers studied electricity (a strange effect happening when you rub glass with wood, or with strange combinations of acids and metals in "batteries", etc.) and magnetism (a strange effect happening with certain strange stones and iron filings), but an early hint that they were united came from a guy named Faraday, who noticed that some electrical setups were also deflecting compasses, and we had four equations of electromagnetism. We would write them today in SI units with vector operators as:$$\begin{array}{rlcrl}
\nabla \cdot E \;=&\rho/\epsilon_0,&&\nabla \times E \;=&-\dot B,\\
\nabla \cdot B \;=&0,&&\nabla \times B \;=&\mu_0~J.
\end{array}$$
A guy named James Clerk Maxwell came along and researched this mathematics deeply, eventually realizing that it had a deep inconsistency with what we wanted to describe: it was a prediction of the equations that electric charge could not "collect" anywhere, deriving $\nabla\cdot J =0$ from the last of these in apparent contradiction to rubbing a glass rod with wool.  If charge was instead a real (conserved) quantity, you would want $\nabla\cdot J + \dot\rho = 0,$ which kind of "naturally" links the last equation with the first one if we simply modify the last equation to have a term $+\mu_0 \epsilon_0 \dot E.$

The genius of this is that then we have $E$ causing $B$ to change and $B$ causing $E$ to change, and Maxwell derived a **wave equation** which said that even in vacuum ($\rho=0, J=0$) there would be electromagnetic waves propagating at the speed $1/\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}.$ As the story goes, Maxwell computed these and found $3\cdot 10^8 \text{ m/s}$ in line with what was then measured for light, and came up with the stunning conclusion that light could also be unified with the new electromagnetism, as an electromagnetic wave. All this from just adding a reasonable physical expectation (charge continuity) to the mathematical form of an equation.

From that point there were a lot of rapid developments, but the most important here was a growing argument in the physics community. These new equations of electromagnetism had scored a major victory but were known to be incompatible with Newton's laws. You can already see that in the above prediction: it says light waves travel with the absolute speed $1/\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}$ in vacuum, whereas Newton's laws say that things like sound propagate with some speed $v$ *in the reference frame at which the medium carrying the sound is at rest*. If you're travelling with respect to this medium, then you can see these waves going faster or slower as you add the speed of the medium. But the above equations say that this happens in vacuum, with no medium to move. The usual answer was therefore "there is some sort of medium which is not being described in these equations!". The medium was called the "luminiferous ether." What happened next was a crazy international collaboration: Michelson and Morley, in America, had done experiments which failed to show Earth's motion in the "ether" (which is no big deal if we're somehow "dragging" it along with us as we rotate in space, although this seemed like it might predict unusual not-yet-seen distortions when looking at the Sun or the night sky.) We had the English (Oliver Heaviside) and the Irish (Joseph Larmor) working on this oddity alongside the French (Henri Poincaré) and the Dutch (Hendrik Lorentz). A [1905 paper by Poincaré](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:On_the_Dynamics_of_the_Electron_(June)) summarizes the state of this thinking: there exists an ether, but since all of the equations which make us up are electromagnetic, there are a reasonable set of hypotheses by which the Earth can be moving through it and yet we cannot reasonably detect our motion through it. We can possibly measure our movement through it by looking for aberrations in gravity.

In the same year there was a little-known Swiss-German (Albert Einstein) who had apparently read some of Lorentz's works (he mentions him by name) and [contributed a paper with a few bold results](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf): in summary, (a) you can *derive* Lorentz's transformation from these two principles; (b) if you get really precise about what you mean with "synchronizing" clocks and "measuring length" then you'll find that classical mechanics tacitly assumes a lot of things which don't have to be so; (c) the Lorentz transform provides a mathematically consistent alternative which needs to be taken seriously; (d) if you really take it seriously then you can regard the luminiferous ether as superfluous (as well as these ad-hoc extras from Poincaré and Lorentz, like "agreement between [two] formulas... [can be obtained by] assuming that the electron, deformable and compressible, is subjected to a constant external pressure whose work is proportional to volume changes."), and (e) if you really take it seriously then it does indeed form a cosmic speed limit where nothing can go faster than light can, because it takes an infinite energy to get there.

Einstein has stated that one of his biggest motivations for trusting electromagnetism -- light moves with a speed of $1/\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}$ everywhere! -- in the fact that you can calculate one particular quantity two different ways and electromagnetic theory gives you the same result: the current in a coil of wire if you hold the coil fast and plunge a magnet through it, is the same current as if you hold the magnet fast and push the coil over it to generate the same relative motion. The mechanisms are totally different in the theory, but the predicted current is exactly the same, suggesting that the theory is not just "obviously wrong" as the Newtonian establishment had regarded it, but rather is somehow "deeply right." If the works Einstein had been reading had in addition been Lorentz's resolution of the problem of electromagnetic aberration, then it probably seemed like "this theory keeps making huge wins and I need to take it really seriously."

## How does this interpretation of the Lorentz transform solve the problems?

So the easiest answer here is kind of a "gimme" answer in that it does not show you immediate physical insight: it is that the Lorentz transform is mathematically consistent, therefore, there can be no problems. If we compute the inverse transform to $(x, w) \mapsto \gamma (x - \beta w, w - \beta x)$ (where we're defining $w = c t,\;\beta=v/c,\;\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-\beta^2},$ as usual in the field) we find that the inverse is $(x, w) \mapsto \gamma (x + \beta w, w + \beta x).$ This is what Poincaré was saying earlier: the inverse of a Lorentz boost turns out to have the exact same form as a Lorentz boost, furthermore the composition of boosts has the form of a Lorentz boost; all I'm adding here is that the inverse of the boost with parameter $\beta$ is the boost with parameter $-\beta$, which is an additional really-nice feature. The system is self-consistent, so we can just let it tell us its answers.

Einstein himself gives a much more direct picture of what's going wrong: in his 1905 paper he *defines what he means* by saying two clocks are in-sync and he *observes directly* that rulers in a travelling reference frame are measuring a moving length one way, while rulers in a stationary reference frame are measuring them differently. He also makes an explicit observation that from the perspective of the stationary reference frame the moving clocks will appear to be ticking slowly, and derives a new form of the Doppler effect. So these are the sorts of effects which are "getting in the way" of the straightforward Newtonian interpretation.

Much later we discovered a more natural mathematics.

## Rotations, rapidities and velocity additions

You may not have seen matrices, but if you write the above transform as a matrix it looks like$$\begin{bmatrix}w'\\x'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\gamma&\gamma\beta\\\gamma\beta&\gamma\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w\\x\end{bmatrix}.$$This has an intriguing interpretation. Recall that a 2D rotation matrix has the pattern $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$ then we see that these patterns are almost exactly the same except for a $-$ sign in the top-right corner. In addition the fact that we have to choose $\gamma$ very particularly as $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}$ is significant: for a rotation we might well describe a right triangle with sides $1$ and $\beta$ and hypotenuse $\eta = \sqrt{1 + \beta^2}$ and then we have $\cos\theta = 1/\eta,\; \sin\theta = \beta/\eta$ directly. So these are algebraically almost exactly the same, just with some $-$ signs switched with $+$ signs. To really resolve this we need to look for an analogue to the Pythagorean theorem, $(\sin\theta)^2 + (\cos\theta)^2 = 1,$ where that middle $+$ sign becomes a $-$ sign.

We can find this for $\cosh\phi = (e^\phi + e^{-\phi})/2$ and $\sinh\phi = (e^\phi - e^{-\phi})/2,$ which together satisfy $$(\cosh\phi)^2 - (\sinh\phi)^2 = 1.$$ The equivalences go much deeper -- it turns out that once you learn complex analysis, $\cos \theta = \cosh (i\theta)$ while $\sin \theta = (\sinh (i\theta))/i.$ But it turns out that the Lorentz transform can be written in this particularly elegant way as the matrix:$$\begin{bmatrix}\cosh\phi&\sinh\phi\\\sinh\phi&\cosh\phi\end{bmatrix}.$$The reason that this is elegant, of course, is that just like there are angle-sum rules for $\sin$ and $\cos$, we can use the above expressions to find out that $\cosh(\alpha + \beta) = \cosh \alpha \cosh \beta + \sinh \alpha \sinh \beta$ and $\sinh(\alpha+\beta) = \sinh\alpha\cosh\beta + \cosh\alpha\sinh\beta.$ It therefore turns out that:$$
\begin{bmatrix}\cosh\phi_1&\sinh\phi_1\\\sinh\phi_1&\cosh\phi_1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cosh\phi_2&\sinh\phi_2\\\sinh\phi_2&\cosh\phi_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cosh(\phi_1 + \phi_2)&\sinh(\phi_1 + \phi_2)\\\sinh(\phi_1 + \phi_2)&\cosh(\phi_1 + \phi_2)\end{bmatrix}.$$So these expressions $\phi = \tanh^{-1}(v/c)$ (where the $-1$ superscript means the "inverse function" to the hyperbolic tangent $\tanh x = \sinh x / \cosh x$) are the much-needed way to make the Lorentz transforms look linear again. For example, under "constant acceleration" $a$ (constant in the particle's co-moving frames!) a relativistic particle will instead describe a velocity of the form $v(\tau) = c \tanh(a \tau/c)$ where $\tau$ is a time coordinate.

The technical term for this hyperbolic-tangent-angle $\phi$ which corresponds to a velocity is the "rapidity." Special relativity is linear in rapidities.

So, for example, a particle is moving with rapidity $\psi$ in some reference frame; we can therefore invent a coordinate $s$ and describe it as the line $x = x_0 + s \sinh\psi ,\; w = s \cosh \psi$ to get the requisite $x = x_0 + w \tanh \psi.$ When we transform this with the Lorentz transform we find $x = x_0 \cosh\phi + s \sinh(\phi+\psi),\; w = x_0\sinh\phi + s \cosh(\phi+\psi):$ after the boost by rapidity $\phi$, it now appears to be moving with rapidity $\phi+\psi$ (and its position at w=0 seems to be slightly different if it doesn't go through the origin at this time).

## A practical example

If one observer is travelling at speed $-0.9c$ in some frame of reference and the other is travelling at speed $+0.9c$ in some frame of reference, then when we perform this Lorentz transformation with $\beta = 0.9c,$ $\phi \approx 1.47222,$ we find that the first observer now has rapidity $0$ while the second has rapidity $2.94666.$ Computing now the $\tanh(2.94666)$ we can find the result $0.9945,$ the relative velocity between the two objects as seen from either of their reference frames is not 1.8c but instead only 0.9945c. We've gone from 9/10ths the speed of light to 180/181ths the speed of light.

So what do I see when I, on the ground try to measure the one observer measuring the speed of the other observer? I see many things. Relative to me their clocks appear to be running slowly (at 43.6% of the speed that they should be!), and they seem to be crucially out-of-sync along the $x$ axis, getting more and more out of sync the further that the other object gets! Moreover their rulers appear to be only 43.6% as long as my rulers, because they are length-contracted in the direction that they are going. As I watch them get these numbers with these strange measurement apparatii, of course I see them get some strange result like 0.9945c instead of my value of 1.8c -- everything they're using looks like it's somehow "off" to me! Nevertheless, the mathematics of special relativity is 100% self-consistent and we can know firmly "this weirdness never leads to any actual paradoxes: even though it is strange to think that rapidities add, rather than velocities add, for small hyperbolic-angles $\tanh x \approx x$ and so all of my customary understanding of the world holds at my own speeds while all of this broader understanding of the world is mathematically consistent and seems to be borne out by experiment."

For example our particle accelerators these days are big rings of fixed radius, using a magnetic field to curve charged particles. This depends crucially on the prediction that for a fixed magnetic field and fixed velocity, the curve of the charged particles is precisely known -- otherwise we do not need a ring but a disc shape so that the particle can "spiral outward" as it goes faster and faster. But we dump gobs and gobs of energy into these tiny particles and they do not smash into the sides of our ring but go around it normally. It is baked into the engineering of the particle accelerators that the particles must be topping out at $v \approx c.$

But we don't have to care about this for quite some amount of work: in fact for small velocities $\gamma\approx 1 + \frac12 \beta^2,$ so even for $\beta\approx 0.1c$ you usually only have to face 0.5% corrections or something, which are usually negligible. So the wide range of classical mechanics is usually still preserved for anything that's going less than, say, a tenth of the speed of light. If you want to get to the nearest star (~4.243 light years) with a spaceship within the span of a human life (~21 years there, ~21 years back), I can tell you to within about 2% error that time dilation is mostly negligible at 0.2c and you're going to need about $10^{20}\text{ J}$ of energy to get any reasonable living-habitat travelling that long of a journey. This is about the amount of energy of the Sun on the Earth in 10 minutes or so, and also about the amount of energy that the entire human race right now uses in a month or two. So we're talking about somehow needing to drag a Moon-sized solar panel with you so that you can hopefully power some sort of ion drive that will slow you down as you approach, and can then accelerate you back this way once you've gone. (Hope you figure out something super-lightweight because however big it is, that's going to drive the energy costs even higher. The above calculation assumes a mass barely bigger than the Space Shuttle!)

So, that's the easy way to calculate relative velocities and a tiny amount of the experimental confirmation (don't get me started on atmospheric muons being detected at the ground!). Hopefully this shows you that even though things are a little strange, they're not too strange for Einstein to make his big leap in understanding.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it in details. It's little bit technical for me, but I know that these theories are incomplete and inexplicable without math. In fact, math is the main tool in this section of physics which sometimes compel the scientists to accept counter-intuitive ideas. Earlier, I had an erroneous idea that postulate is simply an assumption for the purpose of defining a new theory, without concerning previous results of other scientists. But your answer clarifies that it was not an instantly occured personal idea, rather the demand of its very favorable conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Initially it would have occurred to Einstein as a thought experiment and some intuition based upon his prior knowledge. Then he would have pursued it with mathematical model.

Newton would have similar experience before he developed his theory. I.e. thought experiment followed by mathematics.

I do not see anything unusual in this.

There are some areas (specially quantum mechanics, and particle physics) where it may be extremely hard to start with a thought experiment because, the common sense is apparently defied in many instances. Therefore, in these fields, it may be common to first do math and experiments and then come up with a theory. But SR/GR would also have defied common sense in those days. That is why he was Einstein.